# PHP: last multidimensional array with end-function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array called $response - and the max count is not unqiue. Sometimes it's just 1 up to 4. I want the last array of the second "0":

```
$last_value = $response['name1'][0]['name2'][0]['name3']['name4'];
```

...so, if there are

```
$last_value = $response['name1'][0]['name2'][0]['name3']['name4'];
$last_value = $response['name1'][0]['name2'][1]['name3']['name4'];
$last_value = $response['name1'][0]['name2'][2]['name3']['name4'];
$last_value = $response['name1'][0]['name2'][3]['name3']['name4'];
```

choose the one with:

```
$last_value = $response['name1'][0]['name2'][3]['name3']['name4'];
```

I know, there is the [php function end](http://php.net/manual/de/function.end.php), but I don't get it with the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$last_value = end($response['name1'][0]['name2'])['name3']['name4'];
```

PHP 5.4+ is required for the Dereferencing of Functions or Methods.

Otherwise it will have to be a two parter for pre PHP 5.4.

```
$pre = end($response['name1'][0]['name2']);
$last_value = $pre['name3']['name4'];
```

Testing Environment:

```
<?php

$response['name1'][0]['name2'][0]['name3']['name4'] = '1';
$response['name1'][0]['name2'][1]['name3']['name4'] = '2';
$response['name1'][0]['name2'][2]['name3']['name4'] = '3';
$response['name1'][0]['name2'][3]['name3']['name4'] = '4';

$myLastElement = end($response['name1'][0]); //Clément Andraud's Answer
$last_value = end($response['name1'][0]['name2'])['name3']['name4'];
var_dump($myLastElement); //Clément Andraud's Output
echo '<br />';
var_dump($last_value);

?>
```

Testing Results:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name3"]=> array(1) { ["name4"]=> string(1) "1" } } [1]=> array(1) { ["name3"]=> array(1) { ["name4"]=> string(1) "2" } } [2]=> array(1) { ["name3"]=> array(1) { ["name4"]=> string(1) "3" } } [3]=> array(1) { ["name3"]=> array(1) { ["name4"]=> string(1) "4" } } } 
string(1) "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$myLastElement = end($response['name1'][0]);
```

This doesn't work ?

Comment: wouldn't it be `$last_value = end($response['name1'][0]['name2'])['name3']['name4'];` `PHP 5.4+`

Comment: @t3chguy: no. that's arrays nested 6 deep, and OP wants the last of the 3rd-deep array. your end is the end of the very last 6-deep array.

Comment: his last bit of code and the header prior to it suggests otherwise, suggests that he'd want the output of `$last_value = $response['name1'][0]['name2'][3]['name3']['name4'];`